# Birt Viewer running on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, report, birt, viewer

I downloaded the birt runtine viewer, i tried an example report and it works OK. But if I put the same report in a folder it doesn't work, i changed the path into the hiperlink at index.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL string you typed into your browser? We have our reports in a directory tree, so for example the link would look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/birt-viewer/frameset?__report=reports/test1.rptdesign&sample=my+parameter
```

Where reports would be the directory from the root of birt-viewer, and then you could go as many levels deep as you would like.